# How to display all the products from a category in the homepage of magento?

Tags: product-list, category-products, featured-product

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

That line of code lists up the products from the category id 4. But i want to display all the 48 products from the category id 4 on the homepage while in the other categories i want to display 20 items per page.

Note :

All my category pages are in list mode while the homepage featured category is in grid mode.

Comment: JUST ADD limit="20"

Comment: Hey find some solution here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281060/limit-number-of-products-shown-on-homepage-list-phtml.

Answer (score 1):

you can set category id in action method like below

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>[category id here]</category_id></action>
```

**Edit**

```
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>20</limit></action>

    </block>
```

And for default view of featured product as grid mode. i would recommend you to use your own custom .phtml file to list those product from sepecific category

you can also refer [this link](http://inchoo.net/magento/more-flexible-approach-for-listing-out-products-on-sale-in-magento/)

hope this will sure help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="4" **products_count="6"**  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

This is most commonly used throughout magento themes.

Comment: Thank you but i have already mention that in my question. I want to display all the 48 products from that category on the homepage. But i want to display just 20 items per pages in the other category.